# configuring Hadoop on OS X got the error

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

I got the error:  line 144: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory

After the configuration following http://www.talendbyexample.com/configuring-hadoop-2.html and http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html,

I type:

```
$ hadoop version
```

and got

```
/hadoop/hadoop2/bin/hadoop: line 144: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
/hadoop/hadoop2/bin/hadoop: line 144: exec: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: which version of hadoop? what's the output of echo $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: the current version: hadoop 2.6.0, and then: `echo $JAVA_HOME`, /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home.  Actually, now I see where it is leading, but should I modify "bin/hadoop" with the other jdk version?

Comment: Does /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home contains bin/java? I guess not. Where exactly jdk got installed? Where do you see java executables?

Comment: Yes, it contains. When I went there `$ cd $JAVA_HOME/bin` , and then `$ ls`, I got it. It looks that there is jdk1.8.0_25.jdk installed but the code in hadoop requires jdk1.7.0_51.jdk.

Comment: have you edited hadoop-config.sh or hadoop or hadoop-env.sh by any chance? just grep for JAVA_HOME in them

Comment: yes, I modified hadoop-env.sh following the instruction (http://www.talendbyexample.com/configuring-hadoop-2.html) like this one: `# The java implementation to use.
# export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home"` Yes, now I see the answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hadoop command uses following command:

```
exec "$JAVA" ..
```

That JAVA variable gets set by hadoop_config.sh which gets sourced by hadoop command. Its setted as:

```
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

Which means your JAVA_HOME is not correct. So assign proper value to JAVA_HOME and rerun the command.

Comment: "etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh" should be modified `# The java implementation to use. # export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines//jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home"`